# how to receive gestures while google ad playing

Tags: ios

```
let request = IMAAdsRequest(adTagUrl: adTag,
                                adDisplayContainer: IMAAdDisplayContainer(adContainer: container,
                                                                          companionSlots: nil),
                                contentPlayhead: playhead,
                                userContext: nil)

    adsLoader?.requestAds(with: request)
```

I create the ad request like above. the container is the view which I add some gestures like pangesture/tapgesture etc.
and now my question is that I can not receive the gestures while the ad playing

Answer (score 0):

already fix it by add the function

`func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }`

more details can check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/P-ec0SBpDbA